# Get the Calendar Color from EKEvent in Swift

Tags: swift, colors, eventkit, ekevent, ekcalendar

In Apple's EventKit each Calendar can have a user-definable color, which can also be accessed on the EKCalendar instance as `EKCalendar.color`.
How can that color be accessed from a single event (not a calendar)? Is there any back-reference from an EKEvent instance to the EKCalendar the event belongs to?

As an example, I have a list of calendars and fetch events by start and end date. In the resulting array of events it seems any information answering a question "*from which calendar a single event is*" got lost.

```
import EventKit

let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let calendars: [EKCalendar] = getCalendars() // get some calendars here

let d = (start: Date(), end: Date().addingTimeInterval(3600*5)) // [now, now+5h]
let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: d.start, end: d.end, calendars: calendars)

let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate) // fetch the events

for event in events { // iterate over all events from calendars within [now, now+5h]
   // ?? how to get the color of the calendar of event? or
   // ?? how to get the EKCalendar instance event is from?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [EKEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent) is a subclass of [EKCalendarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem). The `EKCalendarItem` contains a property, `calendar`.

That being said, here's the answers to the questions

```
...
for event in events { // iterate over all events from calendars within [now, now+5h]
   // ?? how to get the color of the calendar of 
   let color = event.calendar.color

   // ?? how to get the EKCalendar instance event is from?
   let calendar = event.calendar
}
```